# Required Parameter is null and ModelState is valid

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have following ApiController Method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([Required][ModelBinder(typeof(CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder))]string[] nameSearchTokens)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        return Ok();
}
```

If I call the method with no parameters the ModelState is valid.
Does anybody know why?

Thanks in advance!